# Overriding Blank Theme Styles in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, css, less

How would you go about overriding the navigation styles for a custom theme when inheriting from the blank theme in Magento 2?

I have a `theme.css` file in my `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css` folder, but I am aware that Magento 2 uses LESS. I can easily override the styles within my `theme.css` stylesheet, but I don't want to have to keep using `!important`.

Also, I am using Bootstrap 3, and I'm assuming that the styles from the blank theme will override any style instructions that match in Bootstrap. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 18):

The 2 ways recommended by Magento to override or extend the styles from a parent theme:

### 1. Simple way

**Extend:**

In your theme directory, create a `web/css/source` sub-directory. (You've already done this part) Create a `_extend.less` file there.

According to the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html):

> "Extending a theme using _extend.less is the simplest option when you are happy with everything the parent theme has, but want to add more styles."

**Override:**

Instead of creating the `_extend.less` file, you create a `_theme.less` file. In this case you need to copy all variables you need from the parent `_theme.less`, including those which will not be changed. Then make your changes.

According to the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html), the drawback is :

> "You need to monitor and manually update your files whenever the parent’s _theme.less is updated."

---

### 2. Structured way

**Extend:**

This method lets you organize your code in a better way. Your changes will be structured. Instead of using a *single* `_extend.less` file to include all your changes, you create an extend file for each component from the Magento UI library you want to change.

Say you want to extend styles from button and navigation components. In your theme directory create 2 files: `_buttons_extend.less` and `_navigation_extend.less`, then add your changes for each component in the corresponding file.

Then you create the `_extend.less` file adding this code:

```
@import '_buttons_extend.less'; 
@import '_navigation_extend.less';
```

**Override:**

In your theme, create a copy of the file corresponding to the UI component you want to change (`_buttons.less`, `_navigation.less`, etc) This file will override the `_buttons.less` of the parent theme.

It is important to notice the difference between *override* and *extend*.

You can read more on overriding and extending in this [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html) or about CSS in Magento 2 in the [Frontend Developer's Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html).

Comment: So lets say I have a Vendor_Namespace Folder, I add there another folder named "web/css/source/_extend.less" and the _extend.less-File in web/css/source/ will know where the corresponding file lies? Do I understand that correctly

Comment: Yes, just create the file `web/css/source/_extend.less` and put your styles in there.

Comment: I has created a _extend.less file wicth import a _slider.less:  <theme_folder>/css/source/ both files are in the same path, but not work, all rules in _slider.less was not found in .css generated files, I am in developer mode and run "php magento setup:static-content:deploy"

Comment: Have you deleted your browser's cache?

Comment: Can i override <theme_folder>/css/source/lib/variables ? how i can change a variable of a less file?(lets say that i want to override the @button-background for example) - i need to write it inside _buttons_extend.less or i can override all the lin/web/css/source/lib/variables

Comment: That is the problem. The styles don't appear on the frontend. Like the style is not there. So where does the style actually get compiled or deploy to?

Comment: This is without a doubt, the best (simplest) explanation and instruction on custom theming in Magento 2 that I have read - and I have spent many hours trawling docs, SE questions researching this to date.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem using Foundation.  The official way to do this is to override the specific module's less file and modify the css there.  It will then be picked up by Magento during compilation

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html#debug-theme-style

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Ultimately I ended up removing all of the default CSS files made by Magento. I found it much easier to write custom CSS, especially using a framework like Bootstrap, than try to override all of the various modules.  You can do this in:

```
app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <remove src="css/styles-l.css" />
    <remove src="css/print.css" />
    <remove src="css/styles.css" />
</head>
</xml>
```

Comment: Good way to commit stuff. But the question is about "extending" a full theme and adding more to it.

Comment: No, the question is about overriding.

Comment: and where to add the custom css?? in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to override **styles-m.css**, then put the copy in `web/css` of your theme, name it **custom-styles-m.css**.

Then use this code in your themes **default_head_blocks.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/custom-styles-m.css" />
        ...
```

Comment: That's not going to work if you want to use LESS compilation... All of the LESS gets compiled from multiple sources into the two default styles CSS files.