# Magento 2 add background image in custom theme

Tags: magento2, less-css

I have extended Magento blank theme and placed `_theme.less` in css/source folder of my theme.

I want to add background image. So I added this code in `_theme.less`.

```
@page__background-image:"url('@{baseDir}images/index.jpg')";
@sidebar__background-color: @color-gray40;
```

My image is in `web/images` folder. Sidebar color changes but background image does not appear.

What can be issue?

Comment: Did you figure out how to add a background image? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No. I didn't get how to add through overriding .less file . For the timing,I have added my custom css & placed that background css in that file

Comment: DId u guys check this to override .less file    http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102994/overriding-blank-theme-styles-in-magento-2

Comment: And this too i hope is helpful for overriding custom theme   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110164/how-do-you-override-less-in-a-custom-theme

Comment: Ya. but only background image css does not work. If I change background color, that works.

Answer (score 2):

Just add style in `_module.less` file of given path below:

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_theme/css/source

body {
    .lib-css(background-image, @page__background-image);
}
```

you need to deploy static-content after add image

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with:
`background: url('../images/index.jpg');`

If you look in the html source of the page there is:

```
<head >
    <script>
        var require = {
            "baseUrl": "http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"
        };
    </script>
```

(assume that Magento/luma is your current theme)

`../images/index.jpg` is relative to `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/` because the CSS file (styles-m.css/styles-l.css) is in the `css` dir.

As for images in modules there is an example in
`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_ProductVideo/web/css/source/_module.less`:

```
background: url(../Magento_ProductVideo/img/gallery-sprite.png) bottom right;
```

where `img` dir is in `vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/frontend/web/`.
It should work with a directory named `images` too.

Answer (score -2):

@users who commented below the question 
It works perferct. 
use this syntax

```
background-image:url('/media/wysiwyg/homepage/name-of-background-image.jpg');
```

don't try to use the url that you get by inserting image from cms. That double braces and media then wyswing bla bla won't work.

Comment: `@{baseDir}` is not CMS syntax, it's a LESS variable (or should be)