# Change icon color of the grid or list mode buttons in the Category toolbar

Tags: magento2, less, toolbar

I have my own child-theme based on the Luma parent theme.

How do I change icon color of the grid or list mode buttons in the Category toolbar?

In `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less` I found `@text__color__muted`.

But I can't find what this color is, where it's declared?

Answer (score 2):

At `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less` define

```
@text__color__muted: @primary__color__lighter;
```

and value it define at `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less`

Comment: Thanks. I added `@text__color__muted: @primary__color__lighter;` to `/app/design/frontend/MyTheme/my-theme/web/css/source/_theme.less` and I think it's working. Is this the correct method?

Comment: it ok. You can understand clearly below link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102994/overriding-blank-theme-styles-in-magento-2